# CREATE new TABLE from a query on another TABLE using ADO

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I need to CREATE a new table from a query on existing tables using ADO query.
DB is MS Access 2003. Is there a simple way to recreate this?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_report;

CREATE TABLE tmp_report  
SELECT Userid, Name,  
  DATE(CheckTime) AS date,  
  MIN(CheckTime) AS first_login,  
  MAX(checktime) AS last_login,  
  COUNT(CheckTime) AS No_logins,  
  IF(COUNT(CheckTime) = 1, 'ERROR', 
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max(checktime), min(CheckTime))) AS total_sec  
FROM 
  Checkinout LEFT JOIN Userinfo USING(Userid)  
GROUP BY 
  Userid, DATE(CheckTime)  
ORDER BY
  Userid, DATE(CheckTime);
```

Comment: Put the query in code block - select the query and click on the {} link just above the textarea. I did that for you, but you reverted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To CREATE a new table from a query on existing tables, you can use `SELECT INTO`(this creates a new table) or `INSERT INTO SELECT`(this inserts into an existing table) statements.

Check [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263.aspx) page, it has nice examples that you need.

Comment: Thank you. I found just what I needed. SELECT (myquery) INTO tmp_report FROM old_table WHERE did the trick.

Comment: I would say that SELECT INTO is not something that belongs in a production application.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton  why do you say so?

Comment: Because it churns the data file where it is used, which causes unnecessary bloat. Most of the time creating temp data in this fashion is a repetitive process, and you would be recreating the same table over and over again, which makes no sense -- instead, create an empty table with all the fields and clear it and append data as needed.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton `repetitive process` makes perfect sense sir.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I'm trying to use your solution (clear and append) but my DB bloats anyway (Access 2003). I.Bagon